# Delphi Xe2 and Microsoft app certification kit

Tags: windows, delphi-xe2

as object, I'm trying to perform compatibility test for Windows 8: any application compiled with Delphi XE or XE2 fails the test **"Windows security best practices test"** and in particular the test **"Attack surface analyzer"** with the following error:

> Weak ACL on MyExecutable.exe allows tampering by multiple non-administrator accounts.
>
> File: MyExecutable.exe Writable by: Authenticated Users Rights: FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES, FILE_WRITE_EA, FILE_APPEND_DATA, FILE_WRITE_DATA

I also tried with a simple empty project but I always get the same error, and this allows me to obtain the status of "compatible with windows 8".

Can anyone help me?

These links explain something about it:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/openspecification/archive/2010/04/01/about-the-access-mask-structure.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh750314.aspx#asa

regards
Daniele

Comment: This doesn't seem anything to do with the compiler or the executable. I'd suggest to try the test again after putting the application in "Program Files".

Answer (score 2):

after further investigation and insights I have determined that the problem isn't the compiler but the acl defined on the executable. You can change the acl after installation through various tools including cacls.exe of microsoft (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490872.aspx)

Eg: **cacls.exe MYEXE.EXE / E / G "Everyone: R"** only sets the permissions of "Read" and "Read & Execute" to the group "Everyone"

Thanks anyway to everyone.

greetings
daniele